# Uploading a binary string in WebKit/Chrome using XHR (equivalent to Firefox's sendAsBinary)

Tags: javascript, upload, binary, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a webapp that uses several cutting-edge WebKit features. It essentially does this: reads a local file with the `FileReader`, unzips each file into a string using a JavaScript unzip library, and POSTs each file using XMLHttpRequest. This works great for text files, but unfortunately it corrupts binary files (in this case, images). Firefox has a `sendAsBinary` method that solves this problem, but it is non-standard, and more to the point, it doesn't work on WebKit/Chrome which we depend on for other features.

There are a TON of workarounds, and so far none of them work for me:

- Mocking a file upload request with headers, boundaries, and so forth in a long string ([like this](http://blog.footle.org/2007/07/31/binary-multipart-posts-in-javascript/)).
- Setting a bunch of headers on the xhr object ([as such](http://gist.github.com/486405))
- Using the `BlobBuilder`, appending the string to the builder, and using `getBlob` to get a blob to upload ([as recommended](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35705#c6) in the Chrome issue thread about this)

What I'm looking for, most of all, is a forward-compatible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

This one worked for me:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
    function byteValue(x) {
        return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
    }
    var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
    var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
    this.send(ui8a.buffer);
}
```

check here: http://javascript0.org/wiki/Portable_sendAsBinary

Answer (score 1):

You can encode it with base64 and decode it on the server.

Comment: If you have easy access to the requested server. I try to access a couchdb from my domain (CORS allowed) to put attachment on  a doc (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/attachments.html#put--db-docid-attname). Will try sebastien trick.