# Can Webkit JavaScript PUT or POST an image REST-style as pure binary?

Tags: javascript, http, rest, webkit, cordova

When my browser downloads an image from a web site, there is no base64 encoding involved. It issues an HTTP command like `GET /image.jpg` and receives an HTTP response whose `Content-Type` is something like `image/jpg`, whose `Content-Length` is the number of bytes in the image, and whose body is the raw binary image data itself. The data is neither encoded using a character set, nor encoded using a scheme like base64.

Writing RESTful resources has trained me to expect symmetry between HTTP `GET` and `PUT` so that, for example, a URL that delivers JSON data when I do a `GET` will then accept JSON data when it is presented with a `PUT`. In neither case is form encoding involved; in both cases there is simply a `Content-Length` giving the number of bytes in the payload, a `Content-Type` header declaring that the payload is JSON in some character set, and then the character data sits alone and unadorned as the body of the `GET` or `PUT`.

I am writing a PhoneGap application that lets users take photographs and them upload them using my application. I had expected that I could design a RESTful interface for this, that supports symmetric `GET` and `PUT` — so that `PUT` commands involve no special encoding, nor involve any idea of a character set, but simply have a `Content-Type` of `image/jpg` and then a mass of binary JPG data as their payload. Obviously this is a more efficient use of bandwidth than trying to encode the image inside of a form. And this approach works fine when I `PUT` to a URL using a tool like `curl`.

But I am having no luck in doing a clean RESTful `PUT` from PhoneGap WebKit JavaScript! PhoneGap is willing to return the image to my JavaScript as either a local `file:` URL, or else as a `data:` URL that carries the image data inline courtesy of base64 encoding. But in neither case can I find a clear way to convert the image into a pure binary format (would I use one of those newfangled `Blob` objects for this? if so, how?) and then cause a `PUT` that, without festooning the request with extra layers of form or encoding cruft, will simply transmit the raw image across the wire to my web server as the HTTP request payload.

Does anyone know how to induce WebKit to `PUT` an AJAX request with a raw image as its body? Thanks for any pointers — or even any useful answers to the effect that I am approaching this all wrong!

Comment: Similar question, without an answer you would like (does not mean that there is no other answer, though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743047/uploading-a-binary-string-in-webkit-chrome-using-xhr-equivalent-to-firefoxs-se

Answer (score 2):

As for the binary image processing, the [Binary File Inspector demo](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/TypedArrays/) might be helpful as an end-to-end example.

There's some tutorial information on the subject of getting `Blob`s from the filesystem at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications). [This blog post](http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/25/upload-s3-files-directly-with-ajax/) describes how to turn a base64 URI into an `ArrayBuffer` and then a `Blob`.

Finally, either an `ArrayBuffer` or a `Blob` can be uploaded [using the `XMLHttpRequest2` interface](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-blob).

[The XHR2 spec seems to imply](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#the-open%28%29-method) that `PUT` is supported, along with a bunch of other HTTP methods. So combining all this you could stuff files in `Blob`s and send them up using XHR2.

---

Untested code sample using the base64 decoding method with some help from [base64-binary.js](https://github.com/danguer/blog-examples/blob/master/js/base64-binary.js):

```
var BASE_64_PREFIX = "base64,";
function getBase64Content(base64Uri) {
   var index = base64Uri.indexOf(BASE_64_PREFIX);
   return base64Uri.substring(index + BASE_64_PREFIX.length);
}

function put(uri, data, onComplete) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", uri, true);
    xhr.onload = onComplete;

    xhr.send(data);
}

var base64Uri = fromPhoneGap();
var base64Content = getBase64Content(base64Uri);
var arrayBuffer = Base64Binary.decodeArrayBuffer(base64Content);

put("/some/uri", arrayBuffer, function () {
    console.log("All done");
});
```

---

That said, I doubt much of this works on even the latest desktop WebKit, much less the version you're going to be saddled with via PhoneGap. You're probably not in good shape to take advantage of these draft specifications.

Comment: But you leave the missing link still missing, I believe: how can I turn either of the image formats that PhoneGap makes available to me into a `Blob` in the first place?

Comment: See the demo; they do exactly that.

Comment: Probably worth including a small code sample to illustrate the Blob creation (in case the demo should change radically over time). Seems legit, though.

Comment: OK, answer is reasonably complete now. That was fun.