# How can I send binary data to server as a file upload?

Tags: javascript, upload, webkit, xmlhttprequest

I have the base64-encoded string of an image. It gets to me from another site, with an `iframe` and the data from `postMessage`. I know this sounds horrible, but it's an integration I can't get around for reasons beyond my control.

I'm trying to get a proof-of-concept working in a PHP test file.

I have code like this:

```
<div id="binary"><?=$file;?></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "/endpoint.php", true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
oReq.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name","abc.jpg");
oReq.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" );
// This fails whether or not 'binary' is base64-encoded and decoded here
// or when `binary` is already actually binary
oReq.send(document.getElementById( 'binary' ).innerHTML );
</script>
```

`$file` is the actual contents of the file. This will error in Firefox, but we only care about Chrome for this project, since the `iframe` is coming from an instance of embedded webkit.

Anyway this data sends up and for some reason is always a corrupt image. I've also tried making the file printed into the `div` be base64-encoded ( which is actually valid HTML ), and then decoding it before sending up. I just can't come up with a combo of encoding/decoding/printing that makes it work on the server side.

I also tried changing `send` to `sendAsBinary` via:

[Uploading a binary string in WebKit/Chrome using XHR (equivalent to Firefox's sendAsBinary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743047/uploading-a-binary-string-in-webkit-chrome-using-xhr-equivalent-to-firefoxs-se)

Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried changing the data being sent to a `new Blob([thatinnerHTML], { type : "image/jpg" })` but then `Content-Length` goes to `0` with `sendAsBinary`. Using normal `send` in this case goes back to a corrupt image.

Comment: better solution: send base64 encoded string to the server. that works in every scenario

Comment: The controller that handles our uploads needs to work for a "real" upload and this scenario. Since it assumes an actual file upload, it uses data streams and cannot decode - without a lot of rework on that end

Comment: you may also have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications but this is draft and not supported by all browsers

Comment: I need to be WebKit friendly as this integration is only going into a WebKit instance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if possible, don't store the file contents in a `<div>` (or anywhere in the DOM, for that matter). If you can, it'd be better for it to be `<script>var myfile="..."</script>`. If you simply must store it in the DOM, it's got to be base64, for sure. And don't use `innerHTML` to access the contents, use `textContent` instead.

Secondly, I don't think you need binary in this case, because you're not going to (AFAIK) transport the binary data from your iframe to your main page, you're going to have to encode it as a string (the base64 encoding), and once it's a string, it's safe to transmit that as a standard value, and the base64-decode it on the receiving end (the PHP).

edit: saw your comment above about needing to make it as much like a normal file upload as possible. I'd suggest then that THIS use-case needs a separate end-point, which receives the base64 string only, does nothing else, and then it reconstitutes the file, and then it forwards it on to the other end-point.

edit #2: you might be able to put the file contents into a canvas element, and then get them back out as a Blob, using `toBlob()`. to get the contents into a canvas, you'll have to first make a dataURL from your base64 encoding (basically, prepending like "data:image/jpg;base64," ahead of your base64 content), assign that dataURL as the `src` of an `<img>`, then `drawImage()` that from the `<img>` to your `<canvas>`.

Comment: I saw something similar in regards to the `canvas` solution which I thought might be too crazy. But after everything I tried it's starting to seem more attractive. I also thought about hitting another endpoint as an interim. I'm trying to avoid more server code in favor of some JS way.

Comment: the canvas solution might sound "too crazy" at first glance, but it's actually rather run-of-the-mill standard practice when dealing with canvas and images. You end up having to shuffle data back and forth to get different transformations or representations. All in all, what I described would only be like max 5 lines of code.

Comment: Hey are you sure `toBlob` will work in Chrome `canvas` element? All googling is pointing to no, such as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123095

Comment: Oh also, I only have it in the `DOM` for my test file... it will come from `postMessage` going forward

Comment: i just was saying that if you're trying to emulate `postMessage` (where you have content in a javascript variable, the `<script>var content="..."</script>` is more accurate for that.

Comment: ah, well, it would appear not (on `toBlob()`). that sucks. i really don't know any other way to interpret a random string of base64 characters as a valid image file than the canvas/image rodeo suggested.

Comment: `canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  
    oReq.send( blob );
    
 }, "image/jpg");` Well now doing that sends it to server, detects it as an image with the right width and height, but now its just a blank white image. Any ideas there? **Edit** It actually looks white in Chrome and flat grey in Firefox.. weird

Comment: Hm doing `image/jpeg` made it go black instead, and that was the actual mime type of that file. I did notice the `blob` size is quite tiny in comparison to the actual image. It's like it's only capturing the dimensions and that it's an image. It looks like I'll most likely need to tweak my server code afterall.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work via the server route so I ended up passing a flag to the server saying "hey this is base64_encoded" It turns out to not be so much rework so thanks `@mr.VVoo`